# How to write a 2 constructors for initialising 2 different private final variables?

Tags: java, constructor, compiler-errors, initialization, final

```
public class InitialisingFields {
    private final String a;
    private final String b;
    private final String c;

    InitialisingFields(String a,String b){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    InitialisingFields(String a,String b,String c){
        this(a , b);
        this.c = c;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InitialisingFields i = new InitialisingFields("A","B","C"); 
    }
}
```

I want to write `InitialisingFields(String a,String b,String c)` constructor but its giving me compilation errors.

for `InitialisingFields(String a,String b)` it says "blank final field c may not have been initialised"
& 
for `InitialisingFields(String a,String b,String c)` it says "blank final field c may already have been initialised"

I don't want to modify `InitialisingFields(String a,String b)` and add one more parameter because it has been used by lot of classes and I will have to refactor huge number of classes.And for my use case I want to used the object of this class with additional parameter.

Comment: What do you want `c` to be if not provided?

Comment: all _final_ variables must be initialized by the end of _each constructor_.

Comment: I want c to be only initialised when I call the constructor.So this way I am not breaking the existing classes.

Answer (score 4):

You should go the other way round - have one constructor that initializes all the fields and have the other(s) call it with default values:

```
InitialisingFields(String a, String b) {
    this(a, b, null);
}

InitialisingFields(String a, String b, String c) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
}
```

Comment: The problem is if I modify the existing constructor then I have to fix lot of classes where this constructor is already used and the count is huge.

Comment: @AmardeepSingh The fix I propose changes the **implementation** of the given constructor, not its **signature**. You will **not** have to modify any code that uses it.

Comment: Great,Thank you very much.